# Error in performing Shepard IDW in R

Tags: r

I have used phylin package to perform IDW on my data using different approaches since gstat package seems to perform only one type of idw.

```
rawdata = read_excel("E:\\PhD\\10 years\\R code\\Mapping\\July 2019 - masked.xlsx")
wholearea = read_excel("E:\\PhD\\10 years\\R code\\Mapping\\WA - Jul19.xlsx")
land = read_excel("E:\\PhD\\10 years\\R code\\Mapping\\Land.xlsx")
rw = SpatialPointsDataFrame(rawdata[,c("Longitude","Latitude")], rawdata[,3])
WA = SpatialPointsDataFrame(wholearea[,c("Longitude","Latitude")], wholearea[,3])
land.mask = SpatialPointsDataFrame(land[,c("Longitude","Latitude")], land[,3])
grd = as.data.frame(spsample(WA, "regular", n= 20000))
coord = as.data.frame(rw)
coord1 = coord[,c(2,3)]
coord2 = cbind(coord1, coord[,1])
rw.idw = phylin::idw(coord2, coords = grd, grid = coord1,
                     method = "Shepard", distFUN = geo.dist)
```

I encounter this error after a while into the run of my code.
Error in diag(values) : 'list' object cannot be coerced to type 'double'
I have used summary function to find out what's wrong with my data and here is the results:

```
summary(coord2)
   Longitude         Latitude       coord[, 1]   
 Min.   :-93.72   Min.   :28.84   Min.   :941.4  
 1st Qu.:-92.77   1st Qu.:29.01   1st Qu.:955.9  
 Median :-91.04   Median :29.24   Median :957.0  
 Mean   :-90.99   Mean   :29.29   Mean   :957.1  
 3rd Qu.:-88.92   3rd Qu.:29.49   3rd Qu.:959.6  
 Max.   :-88.41   Max.   :30.30   Max.   :978.7
```

```
summary(coord1)
   Longitude         Latitude    
 Min.   :-93.72   Min.   :28.84  
 1st Qu.:-92.77   1st Qu.:29.01  
 Median :-91.04   Median :29.24  
 Mean   :-90.99   Mean   :29.29  
 3rd Qu.:-88.92   3rd Qu.:29.49  
 Max.   :-88.41   Max.   :30.30
```

```
summary(grd)
       x1               x2       
 Min.   :-93.70   Min.   :28.85  
 1st Qu.:-92.38   1st Qu.:29.27  
 Median :-91.06   Median :29.70  
 Mean   :-91.06   Mean   :29.70  
 3rd Qu.:-89.74   3rd Qu.:30.12  
 Max.   :-88.42   Max.   :30.54
```

How can I address this matter?

Comment: Is the error in the `idw` call? If it is then it must be something to do with the shape or structure of the data you have passed to it. We can't tell what that is without your original data files or you telling us what the data looks like. What does `summary` say on your objects `coord2`, `grd` and `coord1`?  Please edit your question and add this important information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the documentation is wrong.

It says:

```
idw(values, coords, grid, method = "Shepard", p = 2, R = 2, N = 15,
     distFUN = geo.dist, ...)
```

and then

```
Arguments:

  values: A table of points to be interpolated. Table must contain x
          and y locations, and a column of values to be interpolated.

  coords: A table wit x and y coordinates of the samples.
```

which sounds like `values` should have the coordinates and values that you are interpolating from, but then `coords` duplicates those coordinates. But looking at the examples in `?idw` shows that the first argument, `values` is only ever a simple vector of values.

So I think all the information for the first two arguments are in the three columns of your `coord2` data frame, and you can do this:

```
rw.idw = idw(values = coord2[,3], coords = coord2[,1:2], grid = grd, method = "Shepard", distFUN = geo.dist)
```

I've submitted a bug report for you: https://github.com/ptarroso/phylin/issues/1

The documentation for the `krig` function in that package seems correct for `idw`, so I suspect they changed something and only updated the documentation for `krig`. This seems right for `idw` as well:

```
Arguments:

  values: A vector of values per sampled location.

  coords: A table containing longitude and latitude of sample locations
          for each value.

    grid: A table containing the coordinates of locations to
          interpolate
```

Comment: Thank you. This really helped and finally, I got results.

Comment: The authors have fixed it and the correction will appear next time they upload to CRAN. Thanks for helping to make open source better!